# jQuery $.extend is not overwriting the values of my settings

Tags: jquery, frameworks

I'm trying to write my own framework and I have an issue with overwriting the defaultsettings of my project. At first I thought using a loop to replace the defaultSettings with settings but then I found $.extend, which should be easier. I however cannot seem to overwrite the defaultSettings with my settings

These are the defaultSettings

```
var defaultSettings = {
    authenticFilter: 'off',
    randomizeHeaders: {state: 'off', topHeaderElement: 'h1', bottomHeaderElement: 'h2', topHeaderClass: ["hl1", "hl3"], bottomHeaderClass: ["hl4", "hl2"]}, 
    hoverFilter: 'off', 
}
```

And these are the settings that should overwrite the defaultSettings

```
var settings = {
    authenticFilter: 'on', 
    randomizeHeaders: {state: 'on', topHeaderElement: 'h1', bottomHeaderElement: 'h2', topHeaderClass: ["hl1", "hl3"], bottomHeaderClass: ["hl4", "hl2"]}, 
    hoverFilter: 'on'
};
```

I've both tried

```
var options = $.extend(true, defaultSettings , settings);
```

And

```
 var options = $.extend({}, defaultSettings , settings);
```

But neither seems to work and my code defaults to the defaultSettings. Is extend the way to go here and if so, why doesn't this work?

```js
    var defaultSettings = {
        authenticFilter: 'off',
        randomizeHeaders: {state: 'off', topHeaderElement: 'h1', bottomHeaderElement: 'h2', topHeaderClass: ["hl1", "hl3"], bottomHeaderClass: ["hl4", "hl2"]}, 
        hoverFilter: 'off', 
    }

var settings = {
    authenticFilter: 'on', 
    randomizeHeaders: {state: 'on', topHeaderElement: 'h1', bottomHeaderElement: 'h2', topHeaderClass: ["hl1", "hl3"], bottomHeaderClass: ["hl4", "hl2"]}, 
    hoverFilter: 'on'
};

var options = $.extend(true, defaultSettings, settings);
console.log(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works just as expected [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWbOmO). `options` gets `hoverFilter: 'on'`, etc. Can you show an exact sequence of code that reproduces the problem, preferably in a snippet here in the question?

Comment: I've added the code snippet, but somehow it works here. Could the problem perhaps be that I pass on "settings" like this "var Papery = function (selector, settings)"

Comment: I fixed it by deleting "selector" that essentially did nothing. Thanks for the help!